# Arithmetic Bit Shift of Double Variable Data Type in C

Tags: c, math, pointers, matrix, shift

I am trying to arithmetic bit shift a double data type in C.  I was wondering if this is the correct way to do it:

NOTE: firdelay[ ][ ] is declared in main as 
    double firdelay[8][12]

```
void function1(double firdelay[][12]) {
    int * shiftptr;

    // Cast address of element of 2D matrix (type double) to integer pointer
    *shiftptr = (int *) (&firdelay[0][5]); 

    // Dereference integer pointer and shift right by 12 bits
    *shiftptr >>= 12; 
}
```

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by bit shifting a double?

Comment: I am converting a simulink model to C, in the model a double is shifted right arithmetically by 12 bits using the Shift Arithmetic block.  Therefore I need to do the same thing in C.

Comment: Can you point to some link describing the model? I really doubt one can get something meaningful by bit shifting a double.

Comment: This model is number --> converted to double --> bit shift right by 12 bits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bitwise shifting a floating point data type will not give you the result you're looking for.

In Simulink, the Shift Arithmetic block only does bit shifting for integer data types. If you feed it a floating point type it divides the input signal by `2^N` where N is the number of bits to shift specified in the mask dialog box.

**EDIT:** 
Since you don't have the capability to perform any floating point math your options are:

- understand the [layout](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) of a floating point single precision number, then figure out how to manipulate it bitwise to achieve division.
- convert whatever algorithm you're porting to use fixed point data types instead of floating point

I'd recommend option 2, it's a whole lot easier than 1

Comment: So basically you are saying I should just divide by 2^N instead of bitshifting?  Hmm.. I need to convert this model to assembly after the C code is done, any idea how I would extend the method down to assembly?  (each data word is 16 bits in my assembly)

Comment: Yes, if the input data type is floating point you should divide. Why do you need to convert the C to assembly manually? Your compiler will take care of that. Assuming your platform supports floating point data the compiler will know what assembly instruction to generate to do a float divide.

Comment: @starbox: to convert to assembly, ask your compiler to do it for you (`-S` switch for gcc).

Comment: @Praetorian: I am writing assembly code for a processor which does not have a compiler written for it.

Comment: @Praetorian: A multicore processor that is, with 128 instruction word size per core.

Comment: @starbox You'll have to search the processor docs for the assembly float divide instruction then (something like `fdiv` if I had to make a blind guess).

Comment: @starbox: okay. If this processor has a FPU, there may be an instruction for multiplying floats by a power of two (*à la* `ldexp`). Otherwise, you'll have to understand how floating point numbers are stored.

Comment: @Praetorian: lol, my research group designed the processor, there is no floating point representation in our assembly, but nice try, also no divide operation.

Comment: @starbox I wish you the best of luck then! Take a look at my edit.

Comment: @starbox: you could emulate floating point and write code to do the division, etc. It is not that complicated, although the lack of a division instruction is a bit of a problem (although a simple long division should still be possible). I guess fixed point math is the best option, indeed, e.g. 64 bit for integral part, 64 bit for fractional part.

Comment: To divide a floating point number by `2^n` you just need to decrease its exponent by `n`, with some special handling when it underflows.

Answer (score 4):

Bit-shifting a floating-point data type (reinterpreted as an int) will give you gibberish (take a look at the diagrams of the binary representation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision) to see why).

If you want to multiply/divide by a power of 2, then you should do that explicitly.

Comment: Or use frexp/ldexp. But compilers are smart nowadays.

Comment: I am not casting the data type to an int, I am only casting the address to an integer pointer.  According to this site: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitshift.html  That is how you do it.

Comment: @starbox: Yes, that's what I mean by "reinterpreted".  And that's not how you do it, because it will give you nonsense.

Comment: @starbox: The author is correct that that is how you bit-shift the binary content of a floating-point data type.  But that operation will not give you meaningful results.

Comment: @starbox: The guy who wrote this link deserves to be shot. There is no guarantee that `float` and `int` have the same size, and no way to guarantee what the result should be. *Don't bit shift floating point numbers*, and most importantly, *don't use those type punning tricks*. Their behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Oil Charlesworth: I'm still not following you. I understand the datatype is composed of mantissa, exponent and sign bit.  Can you give me an example of what this operation will do?

Comment: @Oil Charlesworth:Thank you for your assistance, but if you had to bit shift a double right by 12 bits, how would you do it?, just divide by 2^12?...See this model needs to eventually be converted down to assembly

Comment: @starbox: It will simply shift the sign bit into the exponent, and the exponent bits into the mantissa, and throw away some mantissa bits.  Probably not what you want!

Comment: @starbox By right shifting you'll simply be moving the sign bit toward the exponent bits, and the exponent bits toward the fraction bits ([here's the layout of a float](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format)). So the result will not make any sense. Take a look at my answer below for an explanation of why this works in Simulink.

Comment: @Oil Charlesworth: Thank you for your explanation, that makes sense.  You are correct, that is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

According to the poorly worded and very unclear [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/shiftarithmetic.html), it seems that "bit shifting" in Simulink takes two arguments for floating point values and has the effect of multiplying a floating point value by two raised to the difference of the arguments.

You can use `ldexp(double_number, bits_to_pseudo_shift)` to obtain this behavior. The function `ldexp` is found in `<math.h>`.

Comment: I agree, the documentation is horrible

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct way to do this.  Both operands of `<<` must be of some integer type.

What you're doing is interpreting ("type-punning") a `double` object as if it were an `int` object, and then shifting the resulting `int` value.  Even if `double` and `int` happen to be the same size, this is very unlikely to do anything useful.  (And even if it is useful, it makes more sense to shift unsigned values rather than signed values).

Answer (score 0):

One potential use case for this is for capturing mantissa bits, exponent bits, and sign bit if interested. For this you can use a union:

```
union doubleBits {
    double d;
    long l;
};
```

You can set take your double and set it in the union:

```
union doubleBits myUnion;
myUnion.d = myDouble;
```

And bit shift the long portion of the union after extracting the bits like so:

```
myUnion.l >>= 1;
```

Since the number of bits for each portion of the double is defined, this is one way to extract the underlying bit representation. This is one use case where it could be feasible to want to get the raw underlying bits. I'm not familiar with Simulink, but if that is possibly why the double was being shifted in the first place, this could be a way to achieve that behavior in C. The fact that it was always 12 bits makes me think otherwise, but just in case figured it was worth pointing out for others who stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to achieve this : just add your n to the exponent part of the bitwise representation of the double. 
Convert your double to long using "reinterpret" or bitwise conversion (using a union for instance).. extract bits from 52 to 63 (11 bits).. then add your shift and put back the result in the exponent. 
You should take into account the special values of double (+infinity, nan or zero)

```
double operator_shift_left(double a,int n)
{
    union 
    {
        long long l;
        double d;
    } r;
    r.d=a;
    switch(r.l)
    {
        case 0x0000000000000000: // 0
        case 0x8000000000000000: // -0
        case 0x7FF0000000000000: // pos infnity
        case 0xFFF0000000000000: // neg infnity
        case 0x7FF0000000000001: // Nan
        case 0x7FF8000000000001: // Nan
        case 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF: // Nan
            return a;
    }
    int nexp=(((r.l>>52)&0x7FF)+n); // new exponent
    if (nexp<0) // underflow 
    {
        r.l=r.l &  0x8000000000000000;
        // returns +/- 0
        return r.d;
    }
    if (nexp>2047) // overflow
    {
        r.l=(r.l & 0x8000000000000000)| 0x7FF0000000000000;
        // returns +/- infinity
        return r.d;
    }
    // returns the number with the new exponant

    r.l=(r.l & 0x800FFFFFFFFFFFFF)|(((long long)nexp)<<52); 
    return r.d;


}
```

(there's probably some x64 processor instruction that does it ?)